# How to call a function with a named parameters through another function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have some functions (with different numbers of arguments) like this:

```
def add(n1=None, n2=None):
    return n1+n2
```

And I need to call them through the other, like this: `call_another(function_name, arguments)`

```
call_another(add, n1=1, n2=1)
```

I thought something with **kwargs:

```
def call_another(f, **kwargs):
   # How to call f() sending the arguments? 
   return f(kwargs)  # Obviously, don't work
```

I can't see a way to send the named arguments in kwargs to target function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `**kwargs` instead of `kwargs`. Artificial example:

```
>>> def ff(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs)
>>> def call_another(f, **kwargs):
...     f(**kwargs)
>>> call_another(ff, a=1, b=2)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Damn it, this was my fail! Thanks. :-)